# Dropdown when using with open

Tags: python, python-3.x

In watching the video located at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpgbECVTryk#t=12m23s  At the 4:10 mark he's showing "with open("\scores.txt" and it's obviously on a windows machine.   I'm wondering if this is windows specific?  I'm on OSX.

I have searched but have not found any answer's to this specific question

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the `with` keyword, that is not Windows specific. 
Here is more information on the [with](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) keyword.

If you're referring to "\" as opposed to the "/" in OSX and Windows, than yes, using backslash for paths is Windows specific.

If it's that little dropdown choicebox at the 4:10 mark then that's specific to the IDE (integrated development environment) or text editor the user in the video is using. There are many text editors that supply that feature, however, the one the poster of the video is using is not one I'm familiar with, and that text editor may be exclusive to Windows only.

Comment: I'm referring to the dropdown that occurs as shown in the video that I shared the link for.

Comment: @Chris'sDad The video ends at the 12:23 mark, after going back about 10 secs, I saw the `with open` you're referring too. Can you be more specific and point to an earlier time in the video to where it happens other than the very end?

Comment: I'm sorry,  at 4:10 in the video is where I'm referring too.   This is where the back slash reference is that I'm talking about.

Comment: @Chris'sDad Ah ok, I think I see what you're referring too. If it's that little dropdown choicebox then that's specific to the IDE (integrated development environment) or text editor the user in the video is using. There are many text editors that supply that feature, however, the one the poster of the video is using is not one I'm familiar with, and that text editor may be exclusive to Windows only.